# Regarding In app purchase in iOS app related to online events

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have a question on in-app-purchase. We do have online classes and events, inside the app. we are having the app in app-store since 2 years. We used to upload the apps and app-store team was approving with out any interruption.
But last 2 months we got rejections from app-store team saying according to the new app-store policy the apps which are using online events and classes need to integrate in-app-purchase. But we only allow users to book the events and classes in the app but online streaming is out side of the app. But event though theya re asking us to integrate in-app-purchase.
So we have a doubt which type of in-app-purchase neeed to integrate inside the app as we are having consumable and nonconsumable in-app-purchase.
Please help us if anyone of you have idea on the same. Here you can see one link where apple explains about their policy.

Comment: explain them that you are just booking the class/ event in the app... events/ online classes are happening in the app... they will approve app... If they don't listen, in resolution center, there is an option for Appeal. Send a request there explaining all details. They will approve the app then...

Comment: we will do that. Is that require that we need to do in apppurchase?